# Get digits after character in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract

I need to extract first two digits after character "R".

DATA:

```
165/70 R13 79T
225/75 R16C 118R
205/60 R16 92H
```

Tried this =REGEXEXTRACT(C2,"^*R(.*)"), but this is not quite necessary result.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2; "R(\d{2})")
```